# How can I put a ListView inside a ScrollView using React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, listview, scrollview, react-native

I'm building an iOS React Native app.  I have some test content and then a list of items below it.  If I put both the text content and the listview inside a scrollview the listview does't work properly (only shows some of the items) but if I don't put the listview inside the scrollview, the listview scrolls but the text content stays locked to the top of the screen.  How do I get the text content to scroll with the listview?

Here's an example of my issue:
https://rnplay.org/apps/GWoFWg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should render the top content using the `ListView.renderHeader` prop:

```
class SampleApp extends React.Component {

  _renderHeader() {
    // your header rendering code here
  }

  _renderRow() {
    // your row rendering code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

`ListView` uses `ScrollView` internally to provide the scrolling behaviour, so wrapping it in another  `ScrollView` is not necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks!  Here's a working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/GWoFWg

Comment: But this header gets scrolled off the screen if the list is long. How to make the header sticky? Using the stickyIndices causes a very bad behavior where the rows being scrolled off the screen are visible below the header.

Comment: @shrutim if you don't want your header to scroll with the ListView, don't put it in the ListView, just render the header component above it :)